# Specs for the method of the model DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2, rspec-rails

If new news is enabled, it automatically removes enabled from the previous news.
I wrote a spec, but they fail. As these spec can be improved?

Post.rb

```
before_validation :removes_enabled


def removes_enabled
  if enabled_changed? && enabled?
    Post.update_all( enabled: false )
  end
end
```

My spec:

```
describe "#remove_enabled" do
  let!(:p1) {create :post, enabled: true }

  it "should remove enabled for other post" do
    p2 = create :post, enabled: true
    expect(p1.enabled).to eq(false)
  end

  it "should not remove enabled for other post if current post is not enabled" do
    p2 = create :post, enabled: false
    expect(p1.enabled).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

Comment: Try reloading `p1` in both your test cases. `expect(p1.reload.enabled).to eq(false)` and `expect(p1.reload.enabled).to eq(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe "#remove_enabled" do
  let!(:post) { create :post, enabled: true }

  it "should remove enabled for other post" do
    create :post, enabled: true
    expect(post.reload.enabled).to eq(false)
  end

  it "should not remove enabled for other post if current post is not enabled" do
    create :post, enabled: false
    expect(post.reload.enabled).to eq(true)
  end
end
```